# Angular foreach loop doesn't provide the facility of using break or return to break the loop. But why?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, for-loop

Angular foreach loop being pretty similar to enhanced for loop of java, I was expecting to use break or return statement to break out of the for loop. But I realized it doesn't work that way. So just want to know why this was not provided by the AngularJS guys? I mean the rationality behind this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not implemented in Angular as there are some issues delegating the implementation to the native for-Each loop.

Check this [**issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/263#issuecomment-8153737) for detailed discussion on this.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Basically, it says that angular foreach relies on native foreach loop, which doesn't give feature of break. So then the question is, why didn't native foreach provide the functionality of break? Any idea?